# Bounding expectation of random variable products

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

Can someone help prove the following upper bounds:
**Note**: First inequality has absolute values.

(1) $E |X_i X_j X_k| \leq \frac{1}{3} (E|X_i^3| + E|X_j^3| + E|X_k^3|) $

(2) $E[X_i X_s] E[X_j X_t] \leq \frac{1}{4} (E[X_i^4] + E[X_s^4] + E[X_j^4] + E[X_t^4])   $

Comment: You will need non-negative random variables for the first one, I think. For a counterexample, take $X_i ,X_j,X_k$ iid $P(X_i = -3) = 0.25$ and $P(X_i = 1) = 0.75$, then $E[X_i] = 0$ for each $i$, so LHS is $0$, but $RHS$ is easily seen to be negative. Think about AM-GM and Jensen, anyway.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks for pointing that out. I had forgotten to add the absolute values in the first inequality. Hope that fixes it. I don't quite get why it needs to be raised to 3 (not 2) for example? I am not sure how to use AM-GM and Jensen in this case. Could you please explain it?

Comment: The first inequality holds iff it holds for constants. So it is equivalent to the inequality $3abc \leq (a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3})$ for $a,b,c \geq 0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So then by what you say, it should work for absolute values even if we don't have that a,b,c>0. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Answer for (1): as shown by  multiple methods in  [Proving an inequality with convexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185122/proving-an-inequality-with-convexity)

we have $abc \leq \frac 1  3(a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3})$ for $a,b,c \geq 0$. Just put $a=|X_i|, b=|X_j|, c=|X_k|$.

Hint for 2): Just apply Holder/Cauchy-Schwarz inequality twice for $EX_iX_s$ and $EX_jX_t$  and the apply AM-GM inequality. [ Note that $EX_iX_t\leq \sqrt {EX_i^{2}} \sqrt {EX_t^{2}} \leq (EX_i^{4})^{1/4} (EX_t^{4})^{1/4}$].